# LazyInitializationException in Thread with Spring Roo 1.5

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, spring, exception, jpa

I have a project with Spring Roo 1.5 (mysql w/ hibernate), I made a Thread class (extends from Thread) because I need call to async operations. But when I tried to get this, for example a property from persitence class occurs a exception. This only occurs when I call from Thread class...

My entity class:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Consulta {
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<DetalleConsulta> detalleConsulta;
}
```

My thread:

```
public class ThreadIngresarConsulta extends Thread {

    private Long idConsulta;

    public ThreadIngresarConsultaCRM(Long idConsulta) {
        super("ThreadIngresarConsultaCRM");
        this.idConsulta = idConsulta;
    }


    public void run(){
        try {
            Consulta consulta = Consulta.findConsulta(idConsulta);
            List<DetalleConsulta> lista = consulta.getDetalleConsulta();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }        
    }
}
```

ApplicactionContext (generated by roo)

```
...
   <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

And this is the exception:

```
011-12-05 18:49:10,015 [ThreadIngresarConsulta] ERROR org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.core.Consulta.detalleConsulta, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.core.Consulta.detalleConsulta, no session or session was closed
```

Has anyone tried to call an entity JPA within a thread?

Answer (score 4):

Try putting an @Transactional annotation on the run method of your thread. If that doesn't work move the two lines into a separate method and add @Transactional on that method.

```
public class ThreadIngresarConsulta extends Thread {

    public void run(){
       doProcess();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void doProcess() {
        try {
            Consulta consulta = Consulta.findConsulta(idConsulta);
            List<DetalleConsulta> lista = consulta.getDetalleConsulta();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }        
   }
}
```